# Generically type a class using a generically typed interface

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

This is a pure Typescript/Generics question. The source of my question originates from the Angular/CDK (portal.d.ts):

```
/** Interface that can be used to generically type a class. */
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around this one, without much luck so far. The problem can be seen from the test code I wrote to understand this:

```
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

interface Bar<T> {
    getData: () => T
}

class MyBooleanComponent implements Bar<boolean> {
    getData(): boolean { return true; }
}


class MyGenericWrapper {
    init<T>(comp: ComponentType<T>): T {
        return new comp();
    }
}

const wrapper = new MyGenericWrapper();
const instance = wrapper.init<boolean>(MyBooleanComponent);

(instance as Bar).getData();
```

[CODE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=29#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJygHgCoD5kDeAUMqQOYRgAicYcAXMgBQCUyAvPtkQL5EIAbOAGdhyALIBPVAHsZAiHBABhGQFsADjJARwyYJoVrdYMeiwAjOQqX5ipcpRp1WjK-MUhCJB76iUAVygvMCgAiABuH1I%20PiIIAA8tKDB9cGh4JGRVTW0TbEkNCBw7aOQdAHdmADpajDJhRiVJAG0AXRZGbCi4wRExKQBxXWhgBAB1KDgNIqhvX1BgMBKmBHUNRhytHXACopLO5Gx53wd-MCCvSuQ1zVYo31iiZ7WQYVSKqZnoDnKIKqGIygY0m01m9342neaXeSiy7GQnzB0Gqi2W7hsIFwTCksg8Si2eXALCiRCYoFhICyIjQGBY1Qo1FocAhQA)

[image]

As can be seen there are some problems with this code.

First, `MyBooleanComponent`, which is not assignable to `ComponentType<boolean>`. Its unclear to me how I can tell that MyBooleanComponent` returns booleans?

Second, if I cast `(instance as Bar).getData();` the typescript compiler is unhappy with `Bar`, it wants `(instance as Bar<boolean>).getData();` but I would expect based on how I initialized/setup the whole thing it should be possible derive the `boolean` right?

I'm not use if I'm doing something just wrong or maybe trying to do the impossible. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is that type `T` in `MyGenericWrapper` is different to type `T` in interface `Bar`. You have set interface `Bar`'s generic type to boolean by `MyBooleanComponenet`:

```
class MyBooleanComponent implements Bar<boolean> {
    getData(): boolean { return true; }
}
```

Where as `MyGenericWrapper`'s generic type is set to `MyBooleanComponent`

```
const wrapper = new MyGenericWrapper();
const instance = wrapper.init<MyBooleanComponent>(MyBooleanComponent);
instance.getData();
```

[Working example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJygHgCoD5kDeAUMqcgOYRgAicYcAXMgBQCUyAvPnCAJ4DcRAL5EEAGzgBnScgCyvVAHtFYiDwDCigLYAHRSAjhkwXaq2GwM9FgBGy1T3zEyFKrXpsmdlWpCESLmRQVACuUH5gUCEQgi4iIkQQAB56UGDG4NDwSMiauvoW2Lw6EDhOAaQGAO4sAHT1GOSSTDy8ANoAuqxM2IIJ4lIy8gDihtDACADqUHA6JVD+LqDAYGXMCNo6THl6BuBFJWXdyNiLgaTBYGF+1cgbumyxZPFErxsgkulVM3PQnMi3EZjKATaazeaPUT6T4ZT48HIcZDfcHQWrLVbyJQ+DSbArgXDMTH2Xw7PFgViCUBwkBIWqUGh0OCQoA)